# Extracting certain rows from a file that match a condition from another file

Tags: python, c++, text, extract

So first, I know there are some answers out there for similar questions, but...my problem has to do with speed and memory efficiency.

I have a 60 GB text file that has 17 fields and 460,368,082 records. Column 3 has the ID of the individual and the same individual can have several records in this file. Lets call this file, `File A`.

I have a second file, `File B`, that has the ID of 1,000,000 individuals and I want to extract the rows of `File A` that have an ID that is in `File B`.

I have a windows PC and I'm open to doing this in C or Python, or whatever is faster... but not sure how to do it fast and efficiently.

So far every solution I have come up with takes over 1.5 years according to my calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a sort-merge join. The idea is to sort the File A on column you are joining (ID). Sort File B on the column you are joining (ID). Then read both the files using merge algorithm, ignoring the ones that don't have a match in both.

Sorting the files may require creation of intermediate files.

If the data is in a text file with a delimiter, you can also use linux sort command line utility to perform the sort.

```
 sort -k3,3 -t'|' fileA > fileA.sorted
 sort fileB > fileB.sorted
 dos2unix fileB.sorted  #make sure the line endings are same style
 dos2unix fileA.sorted  #make sure the line endings are same style
```

if dos2unix is not available, this maybe used as an alternative

```
 sort -k3,3 -t'|' fileA | tr -d '\r' > fileA.sorted
 sort fileB | tr -d '\r' > fileB.sorted
```

Join the files

```
 join -1 3 -2 1 -t'|' fileA.sorted fileB.sorted
```

The other option is if you have enough RAM is to load File B in memory in a HashMap kind of structure. Then read File A, and lookup the HashMap for a match. I think either language would work fine, just depends with which you are more comfortable with.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I'm not that proficient in either language, but with some direction I think I can do it... the one thing that I'm worried about are: 1) doesn't the sort loads the file to memory (which it wont be able to do since file A is so massive... and 2) doesnt the join also loads the files to memory? and then I have the same issue as above..

Comment: sort will use temporary files if it needs to for large files. Check man sort for info to set temp directory. Join should not need to read more than a very small portion into memory as the files are already sorted.

Comment: Thhanks... Ok I could potentially access a linux computer... but is there anyway to do this in windows shell?

Comment: Ok I'm now running this in Linux... the problem I get is that the ID is a number, and Linux seems to be messing up when this happens. I believe its because the number of digits is not the same in every row... here is a link to the data, the "small" file in the zip file is just a sample of the first 1000 rows of the huge 60 gb filehttps://www.dropbox.com/s/tv48m9c9ph6rcsm/SampleData.rar?dl=0

Comment: @MauricioRomero The files you have aren't using the same type of line endings. I have updated my answer to show how to make sure you have the same type of line endings. DOS/Windows uses CR/LF, and Linux uses LF. The join should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, if it is unsorted your going to have to search the entire thing and I would use multiple threads for that. If you are going to have to do this search multiple times I would also create an index.

If you have a massive amount of memory you could create a hash table to hold strings. You could then load all of the strings from the first file into the hash table. Then, load each of the strings from the second file one at a time. For each string, check if it's in the hash table. If so, report a match. This approach uses O(m) memory (where m is the number of strings in the first file) and takes at least Ω(m + n) time and possibly more, depending on how the hash function works. This is also (almost certainly) the easiest and most direct way to solve the problem.

If you have little ram to work with but tons of disk space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting, you could get this to O(n log n) time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is first read `File B`, collecting the IDs.  You can store the IDs in a `set` or a `dict`.

Then read `File A`.  For each line in `File A`, extract the ID, then see if it was in `File B` by checking for membership in your `set` or `dict`.  If not, then skip that line and continue with the next line.  If it is, then process that line as desired.